# Changing the partial derivative to the total derivative in Ampère-Maxwell's Law

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

Ampère-Maxwell's Law, in it's integral form, is $$
\oint_{\partial \Sigma}\vec{B}\cdot d \vec{l}=\mu_0\left(\iint_{\Sigma}\vec{J}\cdot d \vec{A}+\epsilon_0\frac{d }{d t}\iint_{\Sigma}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}\right),
$$
let's take $\vec{J}=0$ to make things easier. We can, then, write it as
$$\iint_{\Sigma}\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{B}\cdot d \vec{l}=\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{d }{d t}\iint_{\Sigma}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A},$$

and since $\Sigma$ is arbitrary, we get

$$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{B}=\mu_0\epsilon_o\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec{E}.$$

Here's my question: is there a quick way to know if can we write $\partial/\partial t$ as $d/dt$ besides evaluating $\sum_i(\partial\vec{E}/\partial x_i)(dx_i/dt)$?

Answer (score 1):

It;s a variant of the notation in Leibnitz' formula  which says
$$
\frac d{dt} \int^{b(t)}_{a(t)} f(x,t) dx= \frac{db}{dt} f(b(t))- \frac{da}{dt}f(a(t)) + \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial f }{\partial t}(x,t)dx.
$$
On the LHS the expression only depends on $t$ so there is no need for a partial derivative. But in the integral on the RHS the expression $f(x,t) $ depends of both $x$ and $t$ so you need to use the partial derivative symbol for the time derivative because  $x$ is being understood as being fixed.